# How to run mysqld_safe?

Tags: mysql

It's the first time I use the Stackoverflow forum. Sorry for my English, I'm french.  I have got a problem to launch "mysql". I'm working on Os X 10.9.5 . I'm trying to follow a course on JEE/SQL on open classroom without success.

I have to launch mysqld_safe : it doesn't work anymore (I probably touch something), it works a few seconds and then "mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/pc48.home.pid ended".

```
151129 05:44:26 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysq/data/pc48.home.err'.
151129 05:44:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
151129 05:44:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysq/data/pc48.home.pid ended
```

Then I'm blocked. I tried to reinstall sql without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had already installed mysql with Mamp, it was already launched. So, I could not launch mysqld_safe on another version of mysql. In System Preferrence, I have stopped MySql from Mamp. Then, it works. Perhaps, it's also your problem... I share.